# Proving equinumerosity of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, real-numbers

My question reads:

Prove that if $a<b$ are real numbers, then (i) $(a,b)$~ $(0,1)$ and (ii) $[a,b]$~ $(0,1)$

Now, we have proven that $(0,1)$~ $\mathbb{R}$, so should we consider this we finding a bijection?

**Can I do this with a daigonalization argument instead? This is what I initially thought of doing.**

Then, for part (ii), would it be enough to say since $(a,b)$$\subset [a.b]$ and we have shown that  $(a,b)$~ $(0,1)$, then it follows that $[a,b]$~ $(0,1)$?

Comment: No, you cannot. A diagonal argument would allow you to show that a set does not have a certain size (typically, you use such an argument to prove that a set is uncountable). But that is not what you need. It is not enough, for instance, to know that $(a,b)$ and $(0,1)$ are uncountable, since there are many uncountable sets that are not in bijection with one another.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Can I not do a diagonal argument by assuming $(a,b)$~$\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Or ~ with the natural numbers?

Comment: And what would that accomplish? Sure, a diagonal argument should allow you to prove that $(a,b)$ is uncountable. But that is not what you need.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Right, I now understand what you are saying. So, would it be best to find a bijection for (i) or use Cantor-Bernstein's theorem?

Comment: I would argue directly for (i) (it is fairly easy to find a bijection) and use Cantor-Bernstein for (ii), although a bijection in that case is also relatively easy to produce directly.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Can we not just use the same bijection for both?

Comment: No, obviously not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i), note that any $a < x < b$ may be written as $x = bt + (1-t)a$ for a uniquely determined $t \in (0,1)$. Explicitly, we may solve for $t$ to get $t = (a-x)/(a-b)$.

For (ii), you may embed $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb{R}$; and going the other way around, you may construct an injection which is the composition $\mathbb{R} \cong (a,b) \subset [a,b]$.

Comment: What do you mean by embed? Can I use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem for this part?

Comment: Embedding $A$ into $B$ usually means finding an injection $f : A \rightarrow B$. So yes Cantor-Bernstein is exactly what you want for part (ii).

Comment: @Pam_22R I mean that there is the natural inclusion $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, which is injective, and there is also the composition of the two injective maps $\mathbb{R} \to (a,b) \to [a,b]$, which is therefore also injective. This is all you need to apply Cantor-Bernstein.

Comment: I see. How can I go about forming these injections? I would need two for either direction so for example from [a,b] to (0,1) can I use something from (i)?

Comment: @Pam_22R You only need the two I've just described to conclude that $[a,b] \cong \mathbb{R}$. You already know that $\mathbb{R} \cong (0,1)$, and by (i) $(0,1) \cong (a,b)$. So these four sets are all equinumerous.

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to use Schröder-Bernstein: you can instead show that given an infinite set $A$ and a countable subset $X \subseteq A$ of that set, you can find a bijection between $A$ and $A \cup \{r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n \}$. This is a good exercise for you.

Comment: Then the bijection you suggest goes from (0,1) to (a,b)?

Comment: @Pam_22R Yes (in the first paragraph): $t \mapsto bt + (1-t)a$ yields a bijection $(0,1) \to (a,b)$ with inverse $x \mapsto (a-x)/(a-b)$.

Comment: So, can I say let $f: (0,1)\to (a,b)$ be defined by $f(x)= \frac{x-a}{b-a}$? Then I would have to show it is a bijection.

Comment: @Pam_22R The map you have written down goes from $(a,b)$ to $(0,1)$. And to show that it is a bijection, you can simply exhibit an inverse (I have already told you what the inverse function is).

Comment: I am getting confused with what you are referring to. Then, what I wrote down is fine? It does go from $(0,1)$ to  $(a,b)$?

Comment: @Pam_22R I don't understand what the issue is. Your map $f$ is definitely *not* a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(a,b)$. Take for instance $(a,b) = (-1,0)$. Then $f(x) = x + 1$; surely you agree that this is not a map from $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0)$, but that it is a bijection from $(-1,0)$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I actually got it, I was just reading it wrong. I wrote it wrong on my paper and didn't notice it until I showed it was a bijection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68046/discussion-between-alex-provost-and-pam-22r).